# As tuples are immutable, does it mean that in a database when a value in a row is modified the tuple containing this value is entirely reassigned?

Tags: tuples, immutability

A record in a database is a tuple. A tuple is immutable. When a value of a record is changed , is the tuple entirely reaffected ? If so, is it still efficient (I guess yes) ? Why this data structure used then in databases ?

Comment: In which language ? which ORM ? which database ?

Comment: I read general presentation of relationnal database and records are often named tuples. I want to know if it was because of their immutability.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a category error.

Tuples are immutable in Python.

The Python concept of immutability doesn't really apply to databases, or to the underlying mathematical concept of tuples that they both reference.

A database may or may not change tuples in-place, but the reasons behind that decision don't really have anything to do with the Python concept of immutability.

Comment: Thanks. It's just that records are called tuples in general presentation of relational database and I wanted to know more.

Comment: @DevernayStéphane - Yeah, they're both referring to the same concept from mathematics, which doesn't involve immutability in itself